# Iterating through a multidimensional array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, numpy, iteration

I have created a multidimensional array in Python like this:

```
self.cells = np.empty((r,c),dtype=np.object)
```

Now I want to iterate through all elements of my twodimensional array, and I do not care about the order. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's clear you're using numpy.  With numpy you can just do:

```
for cell in self.cells.flat:
    do_somethin(cell)
```

Comment: I think now there is a more effective way of doing this with [`numpy.nditer()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html)

Answer (score 32):

If you need to change the values of the individual cells then ndenumerate (in numpy) is your friend. Even if you don't it probably still is!

```
for index,value in ndenumerate( self.cells ):
    do_something( value )
    self.cells[index] = new_value
```

Answer (score 19):

Just iterate over one dimension, then the other.

```
for row in self.cells:
    for cell in row:
        do_something(cell)
```

Of course, with only two dimensions, you can compress this down to a single loop using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or generator expression, but that's not very scalable or readable:

```
for cell in (cell for row in self.cells for cell in row):
    do_something(cell)
```

If you need to scale this to multiple dimensions and really want a flat list, you can [write a `flatten` function](http://rightfootin.blogspot.com/2006/09/more-on-python-flatten.html).

Comment: You got it wrong. It should be: for cell in [cell for row in self.cells for cell in row]: do_something(cell)

Comment: Isn't the way he did it fine? It's just a generator expression instead of a list comprehension...am I missing something? O.o

Answer (score 8):

you can get the index of each element as well as the element itself using enumerate command:

```
for (i,row) in enumerate(cells):
  for (j,value) in enumerate(row):
    print i,j,value
```

`i`,`j` contain the row and column index of the element and `value` is the element itself.

Answer (score 7):

How about this:

```
import itertools
for cell in itertools.chain(*self.cells):
    cell.drawCell(surface, posx, posy)
```

Comment: `itertools.chain.from_iterable(self.cells)`

Answer (score 6):

No one has an answer that will work form arbitrarily many dimensions without numpy, so I'll put here a recursive solution that I've used

```
def iterThrough(lists):
  if not hasattr(lists[0], '__iter__'):
    for val in lists:
      yield val
  else:
    for l in lists:
      for val in iterThrough(l):
        yield val

for val in iterThrough(
  [[[111,112,113],[121,122,123],[131,132,133]],
   [[211,212,213],[221,222,223],[231,232,233]],
   [[311,312,313],[321,322,323],[331,332,333]]]):
  print(val)
  # 111
  # 112
  # 113
  # 121
  # ..
```

This doesn't have very good error checking but it works for me

Answer (score 4):

It may be also worth to mention `itertools.product()`.

```
cells = [[x*y for y in range(5)] for x in range(10)]
for x,y in itertools.product(range(10), range(5)):
    print("(%d, %d) %d" % (x,y,cells[x][y]))
```

It can create cartesian product of an arbitrary number of iterables:

```
cells = [[[x*y*z for z in range(3)] for y in range(5)] for x in range(10)]
for x,y,z in itertools.product(range(10), range(5), range(3)):
    print("(%d, %d, %d) %d" % (x,y,z,cells[x][y][z]))
```