# How to iterate over this n-dimensional dataset?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, iteration

I have a `dataset` which has 4 dimensions (for now...) and I need to iterate over it.

To access a value in the `dataset`, I do this:

```
value = dataset[i,j,k,l]
```

Now, I can get the `shape` for the `dataset`:

```
shape = [4,5,2,6]
```

The values in `shape` represent the length of the dimension.

How, given the number of dimensions, can I iterate over all the elements in my dataset? Here is an example:

```
for i in range(shape[0]):
    for j in range(shape[1]):
        for k in range(shape[2]):
            for l in range(shape[3]):
                print('BOOM')
                value = dataset[i,j,k,l]
```

In the future, the `shape` may change. So for example, `shape` may have 10 elements rather than the current 4.

Is there a nice and clean way to do this with Python 3?

Comment: I think a [recursive](http://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php) solution will be the best solution for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating through a multidimensional array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971678/iterating-through-a-multidimensional-array-in-python)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to iterate over the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) <sup>1</sup> of some values (in this case the indices):

```
import itertools
shape = [4,5,2,6]
for idx in itertools.product(*[range(s) for s in shape]):
    value = dataset[idx]
    print(idx, value)
    # i would be "idx[0]", j "idx[1]" and so on...
```

---

However if it's a numpy array you want to iterate over, it *could* be easier to use [`np.ndenumerate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.random([4,5,2,6])
for idx, value in np.ndenumerate(arr):
    print(idx, value)
    # i would be "idx[0]", j "idx[1]" and so on...
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You asked for clarification what `itertools.product(*[range(s) for s in shape])` actually does. So I'll explain it in more details.

For example is you have this loop:

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(8):
        # do whatever
```

This can also be written using `product` as:

```
for i, j in itertools.product(range(10), range(8)):
#                                        ^^^^^^^^---- the inner for loop
#                             ^^^^^^^^^-------------- the outer for loop
    # do whatever
```

That means `product` is just a handy way of reducing the number of **independant** for-loops.

If you want to convert a variable number of `for`-loops to a `product` you essentially need two steps:

```
# Create the "values" each for-loop iterates over
loopover = [range(s) for s in shape]

# Unpack the list using "*" operator because "product" needs them as 
# different positional arguments:
prod = itertools.product(*loopover)

for idx in prod:
     i_0, i_1, ..., i_n = idx   # index is a tuple that can be unpacked if you know the number of values.
                                # The "..." has to be replaced with the variables in real code!
     # do whatever
```

That's equivalent to:

```
for i_1 in range(shape[0]):
    for i_2 in range(shape[1]):
        ... # more loops
            for i_n in range(shape[n]):  # n is the length of the "shape" object
                # do whatever
```

Comment: You don't need to. Indexing using `[i, j, k, l]` is equivalent to `[(i, j, k, l)]` and `idx` is just `(i, j, k, l)` so you can just index it (as shown) with `dataset[idx]`. :)

Comment: if it's an ndarray and you want to iterate over it without having the index iterated as well, you can use ```ndarray.nditer``` instead of ```ndarray.ndenumerate```

Comment: correction, these are functions of numpy and not of ndarray: [ndenumerate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndenumerate.html), [nditer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html)